# Can not lookup EJB2 from other EJB2, but can do it from servlet

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, lookup, ejb-2.x

I develop enterprise project in NetBeans on GlassFish (J2EE_1.4).
There are some entity beans, a couple of session beans and message driven bean in my project.
I use entity beans from servlet (in same project, from web-component) in way like this:

```
InitialContext ic;
ic = new InitialContext();
UserLocalHome userHome = (UserLocalHome) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/User");
```

Everything works just fine.
But when I try to do lookup from session bean or MDB I get naming error. No bean can lookup any other bean.
There are some references in web deployment descriptors, but AFAIK there's no need to define references for EJB.
Also all entity beans have only local interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each EJB has its own java:comp namespace, so in J2EE 1.4, each `<entity/>` or `<message-driven/>` must have its own `<ejb-ref/>` (or `<ejb-local-ref/>`).

In JavaEE 6, a single EJB (or the servlet), can declare an ejb-ref with a `java:module` (or `java:app`) prefix to allow any component in that scope to be able to share the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work for me. I tried to do this: 

    <ejb>
    <ejb-name>TransportBean</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>ejb/Transport</jndi-name>
    <ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Task</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:comp/env/ejb/Task</jndi-name>
    </ejb-ref>
    </ejb>

And got these errors:

    WARNING: This bean [TransportBean] has no ejb reference by the name of [ejb/Task]
    SEVERE: DPL8006: get/add descriptor failure : ejb-ref TO ejb/Task
    SEVERE: DPL8007: Invalid Deployment Descriptors element jndi-name value java:comp/env/ejb/Task

Comment: Where did the <ejb> and <jndi-name> elements come from?  Those aren't valid for ejb-jar.xml (or web.xml).

Comment: These elements are created by NetBeans GUI editor in file sun-ejb-jar.xml (now glassfish-ejb-jar.xml). After your reply I realised that `<ejb-local-ref>` must be placed in ejb-jar.xml.
It was not obvious becuse NetBeans GUI editor (again!) for ejb-jar.xml has no option to do that.
Now `lookup` works great. Thanks for your help!